# Twitter summary card image not showing

Tags: twitter

I've had the card validated, and everything shows up, but the image doesn't.  It does show up when I use the twitter validation tool.

Does anyone know why this would be, or how I might debug it?

Comment: Could you ad an example url and a tweet with that url?

Comment: This sounds like a potential caching issue; was it ever resolved?